# How to recover contacts when UserID is forgotten?

Tags: microsoft-account, recovery

I have a Microsoft Lumia 520. I have lost the contacts and do not remember the userID associated.

Is there any to recover the contacts?

Comment: have you tried recovering your email account? through phone number or any other secondary email?

Answer (score 2):

> How to recover contacts when UserID is forgotten?

You cannot recover your contacts without knowing the user ID. However you can recover your user ID.

**To recover your User ID**

1. If you have a phone number associated with your email account you
   don't need a user ID. You can log into your account on [Outlook
   mail.com](https://login.live.com/) using your phone number. After loging in note your
   username from there.

   [image]
2. If you don't have an associated phone number but have an recovery
   email try contacting Microsoft from that email. They will surely
   help.
3. If you don't have an recovery email or phone, then get the IMEI of
   the Windows mobile you signed in with your Microsoft account before (in your case the IMEI of your Lumia 520).
   Contact the customer care with the IMEI. Hopefull they may find and
   tell your email ID that was associated with your phone.